Using cli parameter in python.mark.parametrized
I need to use the parameter --license from run cli command to exclude the executing of some test cases.
I wanted to use mark.skipif condition but how can there be called the value of --license?
I tried next variant of mark.parametrized but as I got it is not relevant for version pytest 7.4.4:
@mark.parametrize(
    "language, id",
    [
        ("en", 1),
        param(
            "fr", 2,
            marks=mark.skipif(
                pytest.config.getoption("--license") == "com",
            )
        ),
        ("qwer", 3),
    ],
)


Does the --license command line options has multiple values? I.e. like pytest --license foo --license bar?

no, that key may have only 1 value and be used only once. Just this pytest in some cases is launched with --license foo and in some cases with --license bar

Adding --license to the command line is a little more involved. The easiest approach is to mark the test with a custom marker (say, 'unlicensed'):
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "language, lang_id",
    [
        ("en", 1),
        pytest.param("fr", 2, marks=pytest.mark.unlicensed),
        ("qwer", 3),
    ],
)

In order to avoid warning against custom markers, add the following lines to pyproject.toml:
# pyproject.toml
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
markers = [
    "unlicensed",
]

Invoke the tests:
pytest                     # Run all tests
pytest -m 'not unlicensed' # Skip those with 'unlicensed' marker

Update
Here is a solution which is more involved, but allow for the --license flag. Let's start with the test:
# test_it.py
import pytest


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "language, lang_id",
    [
        ("en", 1),
        pytest.param("fr", 2, marks=pytest.mark.license("com")),
        ("qwer", 3),
    ],
)
def test_it(language, lang_id):
    pass

Here is where the magic happens, inside conftest.py:
import pytest


def pytest_runtest_setup(item: pytest.Function):
    """
    Skip test if license matches. An `item` is an individual test.
    """
    # Option from command line
    license: str = item.config.getoption("--license")

    # List of marks from the test
    licenses: list[str] = [
        mark.args[0]
        for mark in item.iter_markers(name="license")
    ]

    # Skip if licenses matches
    if license in licenses:
        pytest.skip(f"license={license}")


def pytest_addoption(parser: pytest.Parser):
    """
    pytest command line now accept this option which by default takes
    1 single string argument.
    """
    parser.addoption("--license")


def pytest_configure(config: pytest.Config):
    """
    Add this the config to avoid warning against undeclared custom markers
    """
    config.addinivalue_line(
        "markers",
        "license(name): select license",
    )

Invocations:
pytest               # Run all tests
pytest --license=com # Skip those with this mark

pytest_addoption() and pytest_configure() should take very little effort to understand. The key here is in the pytest_runtest_setup().

This function is invoked for every tests
Here, we compare the license from the command line against those of the test. Yes, a test can have more than one markers (thus, more than one licenses)
If the license from command line matches one of the license from the test, we skip it


--license can have different values and only for one of them the test should be executed.
sorry that I didn't clarify it in description, now it is added
